# Convergence of function

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Suppose that

- $V(t)$ is nonnegative continuous function ($\forall t:V(t)\ge0$).
- $\dot{V}(t) = -|h(t)|^2 + f(t)g(t)$
- $f(t)$ is a bounded and uniformly continuous function.
- $g(t)$ is a bounded and uniformly continuous function.

In these conditions, is it true that $|h(t)|\to0$ when $g(t)$ asymptotically converges to zero?

--added

I think this is true, but I am not sure.

$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to \infty } \dot{V}(t) = -\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to \infty }|h(t)|^2 + \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to \infty }f(t)g(t) = -\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to \infty }|h(t)|^2$

In the above equation, $V(t)$ could be decreasing function when $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to \infty }|h(t)|\ne0$.

Therefore, I think $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to \infty }|h(t)|$ should be zero to satisfy the boundedness of $V(t)$.

Is this true?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably $V$ is differentiable.

Since $f$ is bounded there exists $M > 0$ such that $-M \leq f(t) \leq M.$

Also $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}g(t) = 0.$ Hence for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $T> 0$ such that $-\epsilon/M < g(t) < \epsilon/M$ when $t > T$.

It follows that for $t > T$,

$$-|h(t)|^2 - \epsilon < V'(t) < -|h(t)|^2 + \epsilon .$$

If $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} |h(t)| =0$ we are done.

Otherwise, $V'(t)<0$ for all $t$ sufficiently large. Hence, $V$ is eventually a decreasing function bounded below by $0$ and

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} V(t) = L \geq 0.$$  If the limit of $V'(t)$ exists then apply L'Hospitals rule to $e^tV(t)/e^t$ to conclude that $V'(t) \rightarrow 0$ and $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} |h(t)| =0$.

It is possible that the limit does not exist without further conditions on $h$.  For example

$$|h(t)|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1_{[n-n^{-2},n+n^{-2}]}(t)$$